# access odbc call failed

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I'm using Access 2003 and this line

```
Set MySQLConn = wrkODBC.OpenConnection("ODBC;DSN=agcat;DESC=MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver DSN;DATABASE=agcat;SERVER=agcat;UID=odbcuser;PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx;PORT=3306;OPTION=3;STMT=;")
```

is now throwing an error (`odbc call failed`) and I can't figure out why.  None of the code has changed and this has always worked before.

The only thing different that happened today is I deleted records from two tables.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the exact error number/message that you are getting?

Comment: Can you link a table from the DB and if that works, check the connection property of the tabledef object?

Comment: Interestingly enough, one of our tables had bad data in it and this caused the error.